# Reading only real contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have a program which reads the contacts and then displays it into the `ListView`. But the problem is that I have total 25k + contacts in my phone and 60% contacts are of google. So it takes too much time to read contacts. How do I read contacts having phone number ?

I'm using this code :

```
 Cursor phones = as.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
   String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


}
phones.close();
```

Comment: the question is what adapter are you using?

Comment: and why do you use a `while` loop? what adapter are you using?

Comment: What I suppose to use ?

Comment: One example will be fine. :)

Comment: there is not one but hundreds of them... just ask uncle google

Comment: I checked but it doesn't go through each and every contact. I also want to use toast to print each and every contact details.

Comment: Toast? what for? you want to show 25k+ Toasts???

Comment: Forget about toast. You should read my question again. :/

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI will give the contacts which have phone numbers only...are you getting any contacts don't having phone numbers?

Comment: Yeah. And some contacts are displaying again and again.

Comment: just use cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null); and pass the returned Cursor to SimpleSursorAdapter, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Where clause can be used to filter the contacts with the phone numbers. Use the below code to retrieve the contacts.

```
   CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0 ", null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC;");
```

For reading the contacts you need  the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using this : How do I edit this code ? :

`ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAS_PHONE_NUMBER. [ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)
.
An Example

```
  String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

    if (hasPhone.equals(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))
      //do your thing
```